# Remove Stopwords in a RDD, Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I have a RDD containing text read from a text file. I would like to remove all the stop words in the text files. There is a pyspark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover which does the same functionality on a Dataframe but I would like to do it on a RDD. Is there a way to do it?

Steps:

```
txt = sc.textFile('/Path') 
txt.collect()
```

which outputs :

```
["23890098\tShlykov, a hard-working taxi driver and Lyosha"]
```

I want to remove all the stop words present in the txt RDD.
Desired Output :

```
["23890098\tShlykov, hard-working taxi driver Lyosha"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list out the stop-words, and then use lambda functions to map and filter the output.

```
stop_words = ['a','and','the','is']

txt = sc.textFile('/Path')

filtered_txt = txt.flatMap(lambda x: x.split()).filter(lambda x: x not in stop_words)

filtered_txt.first()
```